# Inappropriate answer?

Tags: discussion

A longtime user said that my answer was inappropriate. [SN74LS93N is not counting as expected](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491380/sn74ls93n-is-not-counting-as-expected/491388) Please help me understand why it is inappropriate. I have been an active user for a year now, and I thought that I understood this site.

At the time that I answered the OP had not posted a schematic, however a video indicated two potential issues. I pointed out these two issues in my answer. The OP made the corrections that I recommended and the problem was solved.

Comment: I think your answer is fine. Unsure why any user would say it is inappropriate. From what I've seen, you always provide good answers.

Comment: I cannot see anything inappropriate at all in your answer; it is clear and factual given the information you had (and solved the problem) I would ignore the comment as someone having either a bad day or just being - well, you know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the other user have been mistaken by the fact that it is **so** unlikely that somebody actually bothers to watch a video linked to a question that just consists of four sentences, that he couldn't imagine that your answer was anything else but a sarcastic joke based on random thoughts.

I can somewhat understand the logic he followed.

But the fact is: you didn't really make any mistakes. If anything, you may have been a little over-zealous, but I wouldn't blame you for that.

The only real mistake that was made was from the original poster. His question didn't contain all relevant material in its body, and was not up to standards. The schematic was clearly missing. Had the question been written properly, there wouldn't have been any misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks, this has been bothering me a lot. I usually don't watch the linked videos, but if I do, I need to see something interesting in 5 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

Just forget about it. One user complaining in the comments is nothing. The virtual internet points doesn't mean the person is always right.

Answer (score 5):

SE has a culture problem, which is exacerbated by a voting system that doesn't reward the actual *best* answer, while at the same time encourages rules lawyering and gamification by high-rep users and mods.

The worst thing is, SE widely viewed as unwelcoming to new users, many of whom post what seem to be trainwreck questions, but in reality with a bit of work can morph into nuggets of teachable moments. Some of my highest-scoring answers have started with questions like that.

Like [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491234/why-is-electricity-consumption-billed-in-watts-and-not-amperes/491235#491235). And [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/449977/why-are-off-grid-solar-setups-only-12-24-48-vdc/449980#449980).

See, nobody wants to get yelled at when they're asking a question. This seems to be endemic across many the SE sites, including EE.

I'm making it my mission, for now, to push back on this latter issue, at least until I grow bored again or SE collapses under its own weight. The opportunity to help askers is worth it, even if the rules lawyers don't like it.

More about this here: https://dev.to/codemouse92/has-stackoverflow-become-an-antipattern-3icb

Comment: People have been complaining about how _evil_ people are against poor newbies ever since Stack Exchange started. There are still a large number of users who takes the time to learn how to ask a good question. They should be rewarded for their effort.

Comment: Sure, good questions get recognized, that’s not really a problem. It’s those rough-but-could-be-useful ones that get the unjustified mod hate, leaving the asker pondering why they should waste their time and feeling bitter about their interaction with SE. And yet, in all that time SE still hasn’t fixed the problem. Like I said, SE is collapsing under its own weight: mods leaving or being forced out, multiple leadership changes, users abandoning site. Yet... need to grow revenue? That’s not a recipe for long-term success.

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with the question that is being discussed here. Nobody advised to yell at new users. Did I? I was just pointing out that the initial revision of the SN74LS93N question was very incomplete, and this is what led to a misunderstanding between two other users (this misunderstanding being the actual subject here).

Comment: This whole interaction became a s-show. A good answer got flushed, a sane and intelligent answerer got frustrated, and SE does what exactly? Nothing of substance. *shrugs*, 'forget about it', etc.

Comment: @hacktastical Which answer got flushed? Mattman's answer is still there (and has been upvoted a lot). The misunderstanding has been cleared, and I think the frustration of Mattman is now gone, according to the comment he made under my answer above. Nobody yelled at abeforth either. What's left to be fixed here?

Comment: I am happy to find many of my thoughts so condensed in a piece of writing (especially your link). Now the key question: What would need to happen for any of those great suggestions to become reality?

Comment: I've been witness to a series of bad closures lately. Maybe a better feedback system on mods?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just let criticism roll off your back like water off of a duck (I try and do that with some success, not always).

I do think people are a little trigger happy on the downvoting, but that comes with the space at SE, can't make everyone happy. Sometimes people just hate you for no reason or stupid reasons, that doesn't stop me from posting.

I think the answer is good.